# Compatible System of first Order Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am unable to understand certain statements from the text that I am following and need some help in order to understand the compatible system of First order PDE.

1. The text states that the first order PDE give below (where $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$):-
   $$f(x,y,z,p,q) = 0$$
   and 
   $$g(x,y,z,p,q) = 0$$
   Can be solved for p and q to obtain explicit condition: $$p=\phi(x,y,z), q=\psi(x,y,z)$$ provided 
   $$
   \mathbf{J}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} & 
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \\
   \frac{\partial g}{\partial p} & 
   \frac{\partial g}{\partial q}
   \end{bmatrix}
   \not=0
   $$
2. The condition that the pair of equations $f$ & $g$ should be compatible then reduces to the condition:-
   $$dz=pdx+qdy$$

**Question 1:**$\\$
Firstly I am unable to understand the relation between x,y,z,p & q to partially differentiate f and g with respect to p and q to form the above jacobian.
This is basic but need some help in understanding dependency I tried as below:-
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial p} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}\frac{\partial q}{\partial p} = 0$$ Here is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial p} = 0$?

**Question 2:**$\\$
How does the condition of compatibility reduce to: $dz=pdx+qdy$?

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What's the title of the book ?

Comment: 1) $\partial f/\partial p = f_{p}$ is telling you to treat $p = z_{x}$ as a _variable or coordinate_ of the system and differentiate with respect to it. For example, if $f = x p - y q + p^{2}$ say, then $f_{p} = x + 2p$. Similarly for $f_{q}$. 2) It is just an application of the chain rule.

Comment: @mattos, Thanks for your response, I understand that x and y are independent of p and hence can relate to the examples you shared instantly. But I am unclear of its relation with z. I mean imagine an equation $f=z^2p - zxq$. I don't think we can treat z as constant as we vary p or q as per their definition($p=z_x$). Then if z is varying x and y cannot remain constant then. I am a bit confused here. A push in right direction will help.

Comment: That is the point though, you _do_ treat $z$ as constant as you vary $p$ or $q$. I think you need to go through the [Lagrange-Charpit method](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~ymori/docs/teaching/math8402/spring14/lagrange_charpit.pdf) more thoroughly.